# Swift 3 http request not working for HTTPS, works for HTTP

Tags: http, ssl, swift3, https, swift2

This function in swift works for urls with http:// but not urls with https:// i am not sure what the mistake is. I am running a local nodejs express server which uses a ssl certificate to accept https requests but the swift client is not invoking requests correcly, How can i update this code in swift 3 to POST to https urls

Note: node.js server is working fine, i am able to POST successfully from postman via HTTPS, is there some kind of special config that needs to be done on ios side before i can send https requests?

this is the error message i recieve from xcode console

```
2017-10-05 08:17:10.991163-0700 HTTPS Requests[43803:3042492] [] 
nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 
tls_handshake_continue: [-9812]
2017-10-05 08:17:10.991 HTTPS Requests[43803:3042494] 
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, 
-9813)
error in web request
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for 
this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is 
pretending to be “localhost” which could put your confidential 
information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=
<SecTrustRef: 0x6180001273a0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you 
like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
   "<cert(0x7fe4ca810e00) s: localhost i: localhost>"
), NSUnderlyingError=0x6100000462a0 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo=
{_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x6180001273a0>, 
 _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, 
kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
"<cert(0x7fe4ca810e00) s: localhost i: localhost>"
)}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. 
You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be 
“localhost” which could put your confidential information at risk., 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:8443/foo, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:8443/foo, 
NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})
```

.

```
func sendWebRequest(reqUrl: String, params: String, completionCallback: 
@escaping ( [String: Any] )->())
{
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url: URL = URL(string: reqUrl)!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let paramString = params
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    { data, response, error in


        if error != nil
        {
            print("error in web request")
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                /*need to dispatch this to main queue since this is in closure, so needs to update ui so needs to run on the main thread*/
                if let data2 = data
                {
                    //create json object from data
                    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                    {

                        completionCallback(json!)

                    }
                }

            }


        }


    }//completion handler end

    task.resume() //start the web reuqest
}
```

Comment: The issue is most likely with your server, not on client side.

Comment: The certificate for 
this server is invalid.